# How to access error response body with AngularJS

Tags: error-handling, angularjs, response, payload

my head is spinning cause of the following issue. I'm accessing my webservice (running on my localhost:4434) with AngularJS and if something goes wrong, the webservice sends a response 400 containing a json body which contains a message that tells you what exactly went wrong.

Problem is I cannot access the message on the client? It is almost as if it never reaches the client?? (This isn't the case, I've confirmed that it reaches the client already) This is the angular code that I use on the client site.

```
$scope.create = function() {
    $http.post('http://localhost:4434/scrapetastic/foo', $scope.bar).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Call to log: "+status);
            console.log("Call to log: "+data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            console.log("Error|Data:"+data);
            console.log(status);
        });
}
```

If I submit malformed data a corresponding error response is generated but as I said ... somehow I cannot access the message that is contained in the response body. This is what I get:

[image: Trace from firebug]

I've tried all sorts of things but am seriously stuck now...perhaps someone has an idea on how to access the payload of the response or at least what to do next? I'm also dealing with CORS perhaps it has something to do with that.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the format of error message is it json ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and say that your problem is an XSS issue.

Not only do you not have the data variable, but as far as I can tell from your screenshot, `status == 0`.

Your screenshot also says `Origin: http://localhost`, which makes this request considered XSS (since the port is different).  That would explain why status is 0.

Edit: You can use [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) to get around the issue.